# Issue with Matplotlib Dates appearing incorrectly on Graph/ Date Formatting Issue in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to do a basic Time Series plot using matplotlib in Google Colab.

I have a fairly basic issue where I can't get the dates to appear properly, the dates go from 1971 to 2020, so there is quite a lot of data there.

I have saved my code and graph in the below location:

https://github.com/Ianfm94/Financial_Analysis/blob/master/LSTM_NN.ipynb

As you can also see in the below image, the dates are just appearing as black.

I have also tried formatting the dates using "Dateformatter" from the matplotlib package but this didn't have the desired effect.

Could someone please shed some light on how to fix this date issue?

Thanks.

[image: Date issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a feature that automatically adjusts the xticks.
[matplotlib.dates](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/dates_api.html?highlight=autodatelocator#matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator)Please refer to this page

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
# from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Reading in data
nasdaq_data = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ianfm94/Financial_Analysis/master/NASDAQ_data%20US%20Listing.csv"

X = pd.read_csv(nasdaq_data)
Y = X['close']
#print(X.head(n=3))
X['date'] = pd.to_datetime(X['date'])

# Create figure and plot space
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(12, 12))

# Add x-axis and y-axis, colour of graph and increase 
# the line-width
ax.plot(X['date'],
       X['mid_price'],
       color='#69b3a2', lw=2)

# Set title and labels for axes
ax.set(xlabel='Date',
       ylabel='Index Value in $',
       title='Nasdaq Index Analysis')

# Change plot background colour
ax.set_facecolor('xkcd:light grey')

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

# Add grid
plt.grid(b=True, which='both', axis='both')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers, your answer is correct. I had figured out the dates needed to be fixed in the meantime and fixed the plot myself. However, that being said your plot is nicer than mine, I used a seaborn style. I now have two ways of plotting this data. Thanks again!